# Spring boot mongo returning dbref list field empty even data present in db

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I have class  with property

```
@DBRef(lazy=true)private List<User> users;
```

And using mongotemplate methods. Though any results returned showing users[] as empty. In compass I am able to view data getting saved correctly 0:dbref(users, 5, undefined). If I query `@Query("{'users' :{'$ref' : 'users' , '$id' : ?0}}")`its returning class object but users field is getting dispayed as empty. 
Interestingly if change to @dbref User user, User obj is displayed but only for list its failing. Anything additional needs to be done in case of dbref list.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
@Query("{'users.$ref' :{'$id' : ?0}")
```